# Monero/Bitcoin proxy for JSON RPC

Tags: monerod, daemon, cryptonote, rpc

Is there any script available for Monero to convert its JSON RPC commands to bitcoin JSON RPC commands like https://github.com/DeV1doR/ethereumd-proxy.git? If it is already available can you give me the details?

Answer (score 1):

As Monero is not a Bitcoin fork and uses its own RPC API, I'm convinced there is no such thing as a RPC proxy converter out there.
However, you could read the wallet RPC guide (pending refresh) to build your own, with the methods that are actually convertible.